# Cannot create variant 'android-lint' after configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am updating my project's Gradle plugin from 2.1.2 to 3.1.0 but the gradle starts throwing error while build :

> Cannot create variant 'android-lint' after configuration
>   ':app:debugRuntimeElements' has been resolved

project level gradle :

```
 // Top-level build file 
 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-git:0.6.3'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

 // Used to disable preDex, will speed up clean build but slow down incremental builds.
  project.ext.preDexLibs = !project.hasProperty('disablePreDex')

 subprojects {
project.plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
    if ("com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
        project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
    } else if ("com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin".equals(plugin.class.name)) {
        project.android.dexOptions.preDexLibraries = rootProject.ext.preDexLibs
    }
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
 }
```

library level gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

 setVersion '1.2'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'
}
}

configurations {
classpaths
}

def sharedManifest = manifest {
attributes('Specification-Title': 'My App',
           'Specification-Version': '2.1',
           'Specification-Vendor': 'App Vendor',
           'Implementation-Title': 'App',
           'Implementation-Version': '2.1',
           'Implementation-Vendor': 'App Vendor')
 }

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    consumerProguardFile file("proguard-project.txt")
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}

// work-around for duplicate files during packaging of APK
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation project(':exclude-doclet')
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.7'
classpaths files(new File(System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME") + "/platforms/android-${Integer.parseInt(rootProject.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)}/android.jar"),
        new File(System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME") + "/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar"))
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
String name = variant.buildType.name
task("generate${name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
    dependsOn variant.javaCompiler
    description "Generates Javadoc for $project.name."

    title "App $project.version"
    source = variant.javaCompiler.source
    classpath += project.files(variant.javaCompiler.classpath.files, android.getBootClasspath())
    List<File> pathList = new ArrayList<File>()
    pathList.add(new File(project(':exclude-doclet').libsDir,
                          "ExcludeDoclet-${project(':exclude-doclet').version}.jar"))
    options {
        doclet = "ExcludeDoclet"
        docletpath = pathList
        encoding = "UTF-8"
        classpath = configurations.classpaths.files.asType(List)
        linksOffline "http://developer.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
        links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/",
              "http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/",
              "http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/",
              "http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/"
        memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
        header = "AppKit"
    }
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
    failOnError true

    doLast {
        copy {
            from 'src/javadoc/assets/'
            into destinationDir.path + '/assets/'
        }
    }
}

task("assemble${name.capitalize()}JavadocJar", type: Jar) {
    dependsOn "generate${name.capitalize()}Javadoc"
    description "Assembles Jar contaning Javadoc for $project.name."
    from project.tasks.getByName("generate${name.capitalize()}Javadoc").destinationDir
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    manifest {
        from sharedManifest
    }
}

task("assemble${name.capitalize()}Jar", type: Jar) {
    dependsOn variant.javaCompiler
    description "Assembles Jar contaning $project.name."
    from variant.javaCompiler.destinationDir
    manifest {
        from sharedManifest
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives project.tasks.getByName("assemble${name.capitalize()}Jar")
    archives project.tasks.getByName("assemble${name.capitalize()}JavadocJar")
}
}
```

I am stuck with this issue and don't find any solution. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: In order to help you, can you provide both of your build.gradle files ? (one from the project, one from the app)

Comment: @xiaomi i did posted both gradle files please check

Comment: Massive gradle file ^^. I am surprised by the plugin apply into you app `build.gradle` file. It should be `com.android.application` for an app, and `com.android.library` for a library. Can you try this ?

Comment: @xiaomi yes it is a massive project too, `com.android.application` not works

Comment: @KapilRajput Did below solution work for you?

Comment: @VVB yes it works

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same issue with another library as you have.
I could resolve that with replacing this line:

```
classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar)
```

with:

```
doFirst { classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar) },
```

"This is due to new Gradle plugin when AndroidStudio gets updated that goes in conflict with JavaDoc plugin", If you have Javadoc task you must be able to find the same line.